# decodeResource returning null when options are added

Tags: android

Hi I'm setting a Bitmap to an ImageView using this:

```
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inDither = false;
        o.inPurgeable = true;
        o.inInputShareable = true;

        b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext()
                .getResources(), resourceId);
                     //Note the Options parameter is ignored
        ivWallpaper = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivWallpaper);
        ivWallpaper.setImageBitmap(b);
        ivWallpaper.setOnClickListener(Wallpapers.this);
```

Which works fine but when I add the options parameter:

```
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inDither = false;
        o.inPurgeable = true;
        o.inInputShareable = true;

        b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext()
                .getResources(), resourceId, o);
        ivWallpaper = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivWallpaper);
        ivWallpaper.setImageBitmap(b);
        ivWallpaper.setOnClickListener(Wallpapers.this);
```

It gives me a nullPointerException at:
            ivWallpaper.setImageBitmap(b);

Please help me out. Been trying to fix this for hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

public boolean inJustDecodeBounds

If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.

Comment: That was awesomely simple. Thanks.

Comment: @InnenTensai: if this answer answered your question, consider accepting it which will bring 15 points to the poster. 1+ up-vote from me. **Edit** never mind -- you just did it! Good show!